# Calculate the sum of a field contained in a collection that is contained in an other collection using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to calculate the sum of a field contained in a collection that is contained in another collection using java stream().
i only know how to do it if the calculated field is directly in the first collection, like this :

```
return collectionOfObjectA.stream() 
             .mapToDouble(c1 -> c1.getSalary()).sum();
```

but now the "collectionOfObjectA" contain another "collectionOfObjectB", and this last one is the one containing "salary" field.

ObjectA:

```
{
 id:1,
Collection<ObjectB>
}
```

and ObjectB:

```
{
 id:1,
 salary: 4000
}
```

the way i'm calculating it now is like follow:

```
     Double result=0.0;
        for (ObjectA obj: collectionOfObjectA())
        {
            for(ObjectB objB : objA.getcollectionOfObjectB()){
                result+= objB.getSalary();
            }
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: `collection1()` is a method or a var ?

Comment: Can u show us the type of `collection1` and `collection2`?

Comment: sorry just edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `mapToDouble` you have to use `flatMap` like this:

```
return collection1.stream()
        .flatMap(cA -> cA.getCollectionB().stream())
        .mapToDouble(ObjectB::getSalary)
        .sum();
```

Or you can use `map` before the `flatMap`:

```
return collection1.stream()
        .map(ObjectA::getCollectionB)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .mapToDouble(ObjectB::getSalary)
        .sum();
```

Of you can use `flatMapToDouble` directly as @Naman mentioned:

```
return collection1.stream()
        .flatMapToDouble(
                cA -> cA.getCollectionB().stream().mapToDouble(ObjectB::getSalary)
        ).sum();
```

Comment: Most probably this is the right answer. But what OP is not telling is the type of `collection2`, maybe is not `List`. To be more generic, I would recommend `e -> e.stream()`

Comment: @KunLun or maybe `.flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work; that the salary field is in objectB

Comment: @MedMahmoud you question was a little bit not clear, I edit my answer based on your edit

Comment: or simply use `flatMapToDouble`